# Merging Latitude and Longitude columns

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I want to merge a [LAT] column and [LON] column in arcgis to create a field called 'location' [lat, long] column in order to join my information to a csv file which only contains a column labelled 'location'[image], which is latitude and longitude.

Comment: What does the data in the location column in the CSV look like?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming 'Location' is a string field use Field Calculator and calculate a simple string concatenation like:

```
'{},{}'.format( !POINT_X!, !POINT_Y!)
```

Note: my fields are called Point_X and Point_Y because I added them with Add XY tool, you'd need to use `'{},{}'.format( !LAT!, !LON!)`. Be sure to use the python parser:

[image]

Which will append the fields like this:

[image]

Then all you need decide is an appropriate format for your location field.. I've used a comma delimiter but that all depends on what you want to do with the field after you've got it.